# How can I, after launch, discern initial starting inventory for Shopify Store

Tags: shopify, inventory

We started our store in a flurry of activity, and some of our initially posted inventory wasn't recorded. Can we easily find that info?

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably reconstruct your starting inventory by going through your order history, is that what you're asking?

Comment: That's what I had to do using pivot tables and exports from both Orders and Inventory. Not slick.